# electric guitarst playing single notes

Tags: electric-guitar

I recently crossed paths with a young man playing a Gibson using only single notes, it reminded me of years ago when I would bang on a piano's black keys. No it didn't follow any particular pattern but it didn't sound bad. This young man was doing something similar and it too sounded pretty good. I didn't get an opportunity to ask him exactly what he was doing but it has really bothered me that I didn't. I've only been playing a couple of years and I sure would like to be able to play like that. It was kind of bluesy and yet I felt he was choosing the notes and making it up as he went. Anyone got a clue as to what he was playing. Is this some kind of scale or something?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentatonic_scale

Comment: also, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blues_scale

Answer (score 2):

It would sound familiar. He was probably playing the notes from the *pentatonic scales*. There are two, both containing the same notes. Let's take those notes in the key of C. C, D, E, G and A. Thus missing out the B and F from the full C maj. scale. They all sound fine, played in any order, partly because the 'avoid' notes of B and F don't get played. Together those two produce what's called a TRITONE, one of the more dissonant mixes of notes.

Now, we'll take all the same notes, but not in the same order (sic) A, C, D, E and G. Using the A as a home note, we're now in A minor pentatonic. Ironically, these notes somehow fit in A minor AND A major.

Your Gibson player may well have slipped a 'blue' note into his playing, too. Funnily enough, a tritone from the root of the key. If so, then he was playing notes from the *blues scale*.

Back to the piano, the five black keys play those same pentatonics, but in different keys. D#/Eb minor, and F#/Gb major. There are many tunes that only use those note -Amazing Grace springs to mind.

Comment: could you tell me more about these "Tritones"?

Comment: Easily Googlable, but basically two note a tritone apart - 3 tones, or 6 semitones. The two notes played together sound quite strident, and dissonant, although in Blues, they are quite acceptable. A.K.A. the Devil's interval, absolutely forbidden in early music.

Comment: I'm on my way. I tried a little of what you are talking about, nothing so far but it does make sense that it will work.